# How to add 3d models to Android app for drawing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, 3d-model

I am currently trying to make a Drawing app for Android. I have already got the basic things up and running. Now I want to add 3d models to it so that users can select the models and paint on them and they can even make models in the app itself. I found Sceneform but it is primarily used for AR and I don't want to use AR. I would like to know if there is a way through which I may be able to achieve this or should I use some other framework for doing it. Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sceneform** supports 3D assets in the following formats:

- OBJ
- glTF (animations not supported)
- FBX, with or without animations.

###### See Also

- [developers.google.com -  Getting started with Sceneform](//developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/getting-started#import-sceneform-plugin)
- [Sample project on GitHub - Android 3D Model Viewer](https://github.com/the3deers/android-3D-model-viewer)

Comment: I already know about Sceneform, however can it be used to make non-AR app?

Comment: I added a sample project to my answer. You can try to examine it. I hope I could help. Thank you.